# Angular 13 - material table new row, delete row update table

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I am using Angular 13 material-table. I am able to successfully send a request to an api server.

I'm sending a successful post request using modal-dialog and registering. But I can't see it on the current table after registering, I see it in the table after refreshing the page.

Likewise, when I delete a record, it is not deleted from the table, I can see it in the table after the page is refreshed.

How can I fix this?

Here is the "material request lists" where my main table is located, in this area my table is available

**material-demands-list**

```
export class MaterialDemandsListComponent implements OnInit {
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'id',
    'description',
    'createdUserId',
    'createdUserName',
    'status',
    'companyId',
    'companyName',
    'actions',
];

materials: MaterialDemandsModel[] = [];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MaterialDemandsModel>(this.materials);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) table: MatTable<any> | any;

page: number = 1;
pageSize: number = 10;
totalCount: number = 0;
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 20, 50, 100];

workflows: WorkflowListModel[] = [];

constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    public demandsService: MaterialDemandService,
    public workflowService: WorkflowListService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData(this.page, this.pageSize);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.workflowService.getWorkflowDefinitions().subscribe((data) => {
    this.workflows = data.items;
    });
}

getData(page: Number, pageSize: Number) {
    this.demandsService
    .getMaterialDemands(Number(page), Number(pageSize))
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.dataSource.data = data.data;
        this.totalCount = Number(data.data[0].totalCount);
        this.demandsService.loading = false;
    });
}

deleteDialog(obj: any): void {
    Confirm.show(
    `Delete row : ${obj.id}`,
    `${obj.description}  selected row deleting ?`,
    'Delete',
    'Cancel',
    () => {
        this.demandsService.deleteMaterialDemand(obj.id).subscribe({
        next: (v) => {},
        error: (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        },
        complete: () => {},
        });
    },
    () => {
        alert('Cancel');
    }
    );
}


onChangePage(pageEvent: PageEvent) {
    this.pageSize = pageEvent.pageSize;
    this.page = +pageEvent.pageIndex + 1;
    this.getData(this.page, this.pageSize);

    this.demandsService.loading = true;
}

openDialog(action: any, obj: any) {
    obj.action = action;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MaterialDemandDialogComponent, {
    data: obj,
    autoFocus: false,
    });
    dialogRef.disableClose = true;

    // send message to subscribers via observable subject
    this.messageService.sendMessage(this.workflows);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.event == 'Add') {
        this.addRowData(result.data);
    } else if (result.event == 'Update') {
        this.updateRowData(result.data);
    }
    });
}
addRowData(row_obj: any) {
    console.log(row_obj);

    this.materials.push({
    id: 'row_obj.id',
    description: 'row_obj.description',
    ldapId: 'row_obj.ldapId',
    sAMAAccountName: 'row_obj.sAMAAccountName',
    objectGuid: 'row_obj.objectGuid',
    email: 'row_obj.email',
    preferredUserName: 'row_obj.preferredUserName',
    manager: 'row_obj.manager',
    companyName: 'row_obj.companyName',
    status: 'row_obj.status',
    companyId: "row_obj.companyId",
    workflowId: 'row_obj.workflowId',
    workflowDefinitionId: 'row_obj.workflowDefinitionId',
    workflowName: 'row_obj.workflowName',
    workflowVersion: "row_obj.workflowVersion",
    totalCount: "row_obj.totalCount",
    });
    this.table.renderRows();
}
updateRowData(row_obj: any) {
    this.materials = this.materials.filter((value, key) => {
    if (value.id == row_obj.id) {
        value.description = row_obj.description;
    }
    return true;
    });
}
}
```

In this modal form screen, I am creating a new record or updating an existing record.

**material-demand-add-update-dialog**

```
export class MaterialDemandDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
action: string | any;
local_data: any;

workflows: WorkflowListModel[] = []; //Workflow list

workflowsCtrl = new FormControl(); //autoComplete states
filteredStates: Observable<string[]> | any;
subscription: Subscription | any;

errorMessage = '';

@Input() material = {
    description: '',
    ldapId: '',
    sAMAAccountName: '',
    objectGuid: '',
    email: '',
    preferredUserName: '',
    manager: '',
    companyName: '',
    status: 'Boşta',

    workflowId: '',
    workflowDefinitionId: '',
    workflowName: '',
    workflowVersion: '',
    companyId: '1',
};
ownerForm: FormGroup | any;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private materialDemandService: MaterialDemandService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MaterialDemandDialogComponent>,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: MaterialDemandsModel
) {
    this.local_data = { ...data };
    this.action = this.local_data.action;

    // subscribe to material-demands-list component -> workflow list messages
    this.subscription = this.messageService
    .getMessage()
    .subscribe((message) => {
        this.workflows = message.message;
        if (message) {
        //this.workflows.push(message.message);
        } else {
        this.workflows = [];
        }
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredStates = this.workflowsCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map((state) =>
        state ? this._filterStates(state) : this.workflows.slice()
    )
    );

    //Validators
    this.ownerForm = this.fb.group({
    description: [
        this.local_data.description,
        [Validators.maxLength(250), Validators.required],
    ],
    workflowName: [
        this.local_data.workflowName,
        [Validators.maxLength(150), Validators.required],
    ],
    });
}


setWorkflowInfo(value: any) {
    this.material.workflowName = value.name;
    this.material.workflowDefinitionId = value.definitionId;
    this.material.workflowId = value.id;
    this.material.workflowVersion = value.version;
}



postMaterialDemand(): void {
    this.materialDemandService
    .postMaterialWithObservable(this.material)
    .subscribe({
        next: (v) => {
        console.log(v);
        },
        error: (e) => {
        this.errorMessage = e;
        console.log(e);
        },
        complete: () => {
        console.log('success');
        },
    });
}

doAction() {
    if (this.action === 'Add') {
    this.postMaterialDemand();
    }
    this.dialogRef.close({ event: this.action, data: this.local_data });
}
closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close({ event: 'Cancel' });
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

My service file is as follows.
I make sites like "Get, Post, Delete" here and it returns successfully.

**service**

```
export class MaterialDemandService {
private gatewayUrl: string = `${environment.gatewayUrl}`;
public loading: boolean = true;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});

//GATEWAY -> POST
postMaterialWithObservable(data: any): Observable<MaterialDemandsModel> {
    let api = `${this.gatewayUrl}/api/services/purchasing/MaterialDemands`;

    return this.httpClient
    .post<any>(api, JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: this.httpHeaders,
    })
    .pipe(
        tap((x) => {
        this.loading = false;
        }),
        retry(2),
        map(this.extractData),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

//GATEWAY -> GET -> get material demands 1/10
getMaterialDemands(page: number, pageSize: number) {
    return this.httpClient
    .get<{ data: MaterialDemandsModel[] }>(
        `${this.gatewayUrl}/api/services/purchasing/MaterialDemands/${page}/${pageSize}`
    )
    .pipe(
        retry(2),
        tap((x) => {
        this.loading = false;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}


deleteMaterialDemand(materialId: Number) {
    return this.httpClient
    .delete<any>(
        `${this.gatewayUrl}/api/services/purchasing/MaterialDemands/${materialId}`,
        { headers: this.httpHeaders }
    )
    .pipe(retry(2), catchError(this.handleError));
}



private extractData(res: any) {
    return res;
}
private handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.errorMessage instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    errorMessage = error.error.errorMessage;
    } else {
    errorMessage = `\nCode: ${error.status}}\nResponse: ${error.message}`;
    }
    window.alert(errorMessage);
    return throwError(() => {
    return errorMessage;
    });
}
}
```

I've been working on it for a few days but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to provide a new refference for dataSource

In case of adding a new row you have to do something like this

```
this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource, newRow];
```

In case of deleting

```
this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter(...)
```

Comment: yes, where am I going to use it but, it deletes all the data and reloads it. Can you show me how to do it with an example? I'm new to Angular please excuse me